# How to install Ubuntu with the following disk setup?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am following a detailed guide for installing Ubuntu (from everydaylinuxuser), but it does not go into detail about the various ways you can install Ubuntu to a partition. Before using my USB Ubuntu drive, I would like to know how to use the manual partitioning to achieve my goal. I have 3 physical disks in my PC:

[image: Picture of the disks currently]

An SSD with Windows installed on it (C), an 1 TB drive for data (D), and an old disk partitioned into 2 equal parts (F and G). I backed up everything from G, and that's where I would like to install everything Ubuntu (would use Ubuntu only for a class about deep learning at first). [This guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) for manual partioning seems a bit confusing to me:

1. Will the installer show me this 75 GB partion automatically on the window which is the 2nd picture in the above linked guide at the top answer (I can only post 2 links due to being new here) ? I can choose the "G" drive there and move forward with the install?
2. Do I really need seperate partions for different Linux libraries? (root, home, boot, tmp and more)

Comment: 1. No. You'll have to point the installer to it, also, there is no C,G,F designations in Ubuntu. 2. No. Any guide that suggests to create multiple partitions for no reason is a silly one. However, the one you've linked to doesn't suggest anything of the sort. I recommend going over the answers again for clarity.

Comment: Since this is just for a class, and rather than making major changes, why not just install VirtualBox and then install Ubuntu into VirtualBox?

Comment: i thought about it, but i was not sure how resource intensive will be the stuff I'll need to do. Anyway, in the end, I could not find another solution, so I also cleaned out my F drive (had to do a bunch of reinstalls), and format the whole disk for Ubuntu.